# auth0 how to set the days of a regular active user

Tags: auth0

in auth0 the user is active only if has authenticated in the last 30 days.

I have not found how to modify this value programatically

Is there a way to modify this value from 30 to 60 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth0 uses the concept of "active user" to determine how many users are using your applications, in order to charge you for the different pricing plans: https://auth0.com/pricing

If users don't log in for 30 days they will not count towards this total, but they will still be able to log in any time they want. This value can't be modified, for obvious reasons.